# Filter rows based on values inside multiple JSONB columns

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to search a table in a `LIKE %str%` fashion but **on fields inside json values over multiple columns**.

I have a table which has three jsonb columns `change`,`previous` and `specific_changes`. As you might imagine the content is JSON but the structure of that json is not know ahead of time, therefor **i can't** use the `->` or `->>` in query like so:

`select * from change_log where change -> 'field' = '"something"'`

```
create table change_log
(
    id               serial      not null
        constraint pk_change_log
            primary key,
    change           jsonb       not null,
    previous         jsonb,
    changed_at       timestamp with time zone default timezone('utc'::text, now()),
    specific_changes jsonb
);

INSERT INTO public.change_log (id, change, previous, changed_at, specific_changes) VALUES (1, '{"val": 2, "test": "test", "nested": {"nval": 1}}', 'null', '2020-11-12 16:53:28.827896', '{"val2": "Value2"}');
INSERT INTO public.change_log (id, change, previous, changed_at, specific_changes) VALUES (2, '{"val": "testNewChange", "test": "testChange", "nested": {"key": 1}}', '{"val": "2", "test": "testChange", "nested": {"nval": 1}}', '2020-11-15 12:18:35.021843', '{"new": "testValue"}');
INSERT INTO public.change_log (id, change, previous, changed_at, specific_changes) VALUES (3, '{"val": "newewChange", "test": "changeNew", "nested": {"val": 3}}', '{"val": "testNewChange", "test": "testValue", "nested": {"key": 1}}', '2020-11-15 12:19:40.832843', '{"new": "testChange", "nested": {"val": 1}}');
```

**My question is:**

1. How would a query look like that given a **string** will return all rows from the change_log table whose any of the 3 mentioned jsonb columns contain any fields that has a value `like %string%`.
2. how would you make the query case insensitive

Examples:

---

```
  INPUT           OUTPUT(ids)
  "2"              (1,2)
  "Change"         (2,3)
  "Chan"           (2,3)
  "Value"         (1,2,3)
```

EDIT1: I am using postgres version 9.6

EDIT2: Fixed inserted changes to reflect desired behavior

Comment: Why the `id=1` is omitted for `Change`  while it contains `"test": "testChange"` key? Do you want to check the nested objects as well? If yes, why `id=3` is not included for `2` value while it contains `"nested": {"val": 2}`?

Comment: @Abelisto you caught my mistake, i updated the inserted values to match the specified input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common approach for the old versions of the PostgreSQL is using `exists` with some function, like

```
select *
from table_name
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_each_text(column_name) as t(k,v)
    where v ilike '%string%');
```

For several columns it could be done using `or`:

```
select *
from table_name
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from jsonb_each_text(column1) as t(k,v)
        where v ilike '%string%') or
    exists (
        select 1
        from jsonb_each_text(column2) as t(k,v)
        where v ilike '%string%');
```

or `union`:

```
select *
from table_name
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from (
            select * from jsonb_each_text(column1) union all
            select * from jsonb_each_text(column2)) as t(k,v)
        where t.v ilike '%string%');
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ad0c08e56ffa51d3824e3aef241af116)

Note that it will not process properly the nested objects because them will be checked as a whole text, including keys.

To fix this you need to create the stored function that returns all values from JSON recursively.

But it is the subject for another question :)

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem and this solution really helped me. Just for my understanding, what is the name of the operator you used as an alias for the set returned by `jsonb_each_text`? I tried `(k,v)` on its own but the query failed; it only worked when I used `t` like `t(k, v)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can use a SQL/JSON path expression:

```
select *
from change_log
where change @@ '$.** like_regex "change" flag "i"'
   or previous @@ '$.** like_regex "change" flag "i"'
   or specific_changes @@ '$.** like_regex "change" flag "i"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.id
  FROM change_log l
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_EACH_TEXT( l.change ) AS c(e)
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_EACH_TEXT(  nullif(l.previous, 'null') ) AS p(e) 
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_EACH_TEXT( l.specific_changes ) AS s(e)
 WHERE c.value ~* 'change' OR s.value ~* 'change' OR p.value ~* 'change'
```

where `~*` operator searches for case-insensitive matching of the given keyword and the function `JSONB_EACH_TEXT()` expands the outermost JSON object into a set of key/value pairs.

*P.S. Need to fix the value `'null'` by converting to `null` for the id `1` value of the `previous` column or use `nullif(l.previous, 'null')` as the argument for the second JSONB_EACH_TEXT() within the query*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a4e510f8955df44f579328038bf0d949)</kbd>

Comment: `nullif(value, 'null')` However `something cross join empty` will return `empty` (just remove `where` in your query to ensure) ...

Comment: As i failed to mention that i am using postgres 9.6 the provided query is giving `[22023] ERROR: cannot call jsonb_each_text on a non-object`, pretty sure that is version related

Comment: no @vuk , this problem is not related to the version but the literal `'null'` within the `previous` column. Either convert it to `null` as I previously mentioned, or apply `nullif()` function as stated in the above comment and my edit performed just now. Btw, the demo in 9.6 now.

Comment: Thank you very much and i appreciate the patience requiered due to my poor sql skills!